# Prove equation with norm in inner product space

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

$x,y$ - elements of inner product space :  $ \|x+2y\|^2=5$ and $ \|2x+y\|^2=4$. Prove that $9\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2=18 $
Could I ask for any tips how should I start this exercise? I cannot use the fact that norm becomes from scalar product because it's not a Hilbert space, I've thought about using parallelogram law but I don't see how.

Comment: If it is a real vector space, It suffices to expand $||u+v||^2=||u||^2+||v||^2+2\langle u,v \rangle$ 4 times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$ then $x+2y=(3u-v)/2$ and $2x+y=(3u+v)/2$.
Hence
$$5=\|(3u-v)/2\|^2=\frac{9}{4}\|u\|^2-\frac{3}{2}<u,v>+\frac{1}{4}\|v\|^2,$$
and
$$4=\|(3u-v)/2\|^2=\frac{9}{4}\|u\|^2+\frac{3}{2}<u,v>+\frac{1}{4}\|v\|^2.$$
Finally add the two equations:
$$9=4+5=\frac{9}{2}\|u\|^2+\frac{1}{2}\|v\|^2,$$
that is
$$18=9\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2.$$